# Log 4j configuration for adding file name and line number

Tags: java, log4j

I am using Log4j for logging my application activity. In my local environment it was logging like

**Fiilename:linenumber**:  **your logging message**

then I created archive and deploy in another environment then its logging without file name, can any one clear me which property if logger do this.
thanks

Comment: Only without filename, but still with line number? Code that is release built don't contain line number information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the documentation for [PatternLayout](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html). Note that figuring out file name and file number is *slow* (I guess it involves getting a stack trace and analyzing it).

Answer (score 5):

In log4j.properties file set

```
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.conversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH\:mm\:ss,SSS} %-5p %l - %m%n
```

Here %l specifies to generate the location information. According to the spec for [PatternLayout](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html) :
"The location information depends on the JVM implementation but usually consists of the fully qualified name of the calling method followed by the callers source the file name and line number between parentheses."